# How do I configure the Symfony mailer module?

Tags: tokens, 10

I have a contact form (Contact module and contact storage module). After installing the Drupal Symfony Mailer module, a policy for my contact form appeared.  In the Email body in edit of the policy, I enter the tokens of the fields of my form, which I take from /admin/help/token. For example,

```
[contact_message:field_request_bankname]
[contact_message:field_request_bankname:value].
```

But these tokens don't work. I receive an email with tokens, not with values from the form.
How do I understand (where to see) which tokens (twig variables) should be in my policy?
Or maybe there is some other reason why tokens don't work?